# Anime about a guy in a school who has an item that gives him an ability

Tags: story-identification, anime

So this anime is about a guy who meets a girl (the usual) and he has some sort of ability thanks to an item he has in possession. The girl decides to keep him around because of his possession of the item to help her find others with similar items.

I remember an early episode had a guy who had one that basically turned him into a walking inferno. The guy and girl use the items to basically stop the fire that the inferno guy unwittingly started.

Also worth noting this was all in their school.

Once the guy was stopped the school was back to normal and they said that because the powers are illusions they feel real but aren't so there's no real damage (or something like that)

The anime would have come out in late 2000s maybe 2010s. It was a TV series. As far as I am aware there was only one season, so maybe 12-20 episodes.

Watched it on dubbedanime website around 2 or 3 years ago.

Pretty sure I watched it dubbed but my memory might be wrong there. I had watched a lot of anime during lockdown depression.

Comment: Definitely an anime, and not any other medium? This is fairly close to a scene in the visual novel 9-nine- (from 2019). I don't believe it's been adapted to any other format.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @qazmlpok it's definitely an anime. I've played 9-nine- (loved it) and I know it's not that. I remember watching the anime while I was in a depressed period a couple years ago so watched the dub version since I couldn't focus on subtitles at that time. If it helps the I think the item the girl used was a necklace or they were wearing it as a necklace.