# Anime about school (dark haired) boy and (blonde) girl. Both have spirit tools. Girl's is an amulet

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am looking for some help finding an anime that I started some years ago (3 maybe). But I don't remember too much about it. Hoping that someone might be able to figure out what in thinking of.

The story is basically about a guy who meets this girl who decides to get his help (both are teenagers) to find magical items. They both have an item (if memory serves) for her it's an amulet, his I'm not too sure what it was. But these items grant them abilities, in her case I believe it was air based abilities. There is one episode where their school is set on fire, so they rush to find the source which was some other teenager who had an item that caused him to continuously burst into flames and the girl tried to use her abilities to force the guy to extinguish the flames and snatch the items but it isn't until the other guy helps her that they manage to get the flames out. Then they put up some sort of magical illusion or something to make it seem like there was never a fire to begin with (which had actually nearly burnt down the entire school)

These items that they use are referred to as spirit tools or something like that I can't remember. The girl was blonde if I remember correctly and the MC was a typical dark haired Japanese man.

Not sure when the anime aired, but judging by the quality, it was sometimes between 2010 and 2020. I tried to look through MAL but couldn't see a poster that looked familiar for it. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/269528 . No answers, but might have additional details or jog your memory.

Comment: Sounds like Shaman King. Dark haired boy is Yoh Asakura, blonde girl is Anna Kyoyama. He has a wooden sword (and later gets a real sword) as a focus for his power, Anna has a talisman and a necklace as a focus for hers.  https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/ShamanKing First adaption ran in 2001 but Netflix made another one in 2021.

Comment: @jo1storm, nah it's not Shaman King, the guy didn't have a sword, he had like amulets or something, which gave access to a specific element.

Comment: @qazmlpok, yeah it does sound like that is the one described there. Was going crazy thinking I must have dreamed the whole thing but if someone else is describing it then I must not have.